# Open source Graph control library or control for .net compact framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework

Does anyone know any graph control library for .net compact framework ?
Please provide me with links or details if someone knows about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this.
[Piccolo2D .NET Graphing Framework](http://www.piccolo2d.org/learn/comparison.html)

They have a version called PocketPiccolo2D.NET for .NET Compact framework.